# Rigid Foam and Fire Block when finishing basement?

Tags: insulation, basement, basement-refinishing

I'm using rigid foam, specifically [this](https://www.jm.com/content/dam/jm/global/en/building-insulation/Files/BI%20Data%20Sheets/Resi%20and%20Commercial/BID-0151_AP_FoilFaced_DS.pdf) to finish my basement. The foam is going directly onto the concrete, followed by standard framing and some variation of greenboard or paper-free drywall.

Reading the spec sheet for the foam, it says it requires an appropriate fire block. Maryland code seems to say that drywall is acceptable for this purpose, but I'm not entirely sure I'm reading the code correctly.

Do I need to do anything beyond just foam, frame, and sheetrock?

Comment: Why greenboard? That stuff is mold food extraordinaire...for this application, it's best to take the hit in the pocketbook and go with the glass-faced exterior-grade drywall, now *that* stuff is basically mold-food-free ;)

Comment: Who cares about mold? Unless you live in Puerto Rico, Florida, Texas, New Jersey, Connecticut, New York, Louisiana, Mississippi, Alabama, Georgia, North Carolina, South Carolina, Virginia, Maryland, DC, Delaware, Rhode Island, Massachussetts, Vermont, Maine, Pennsylvania, Ohio, Michigan, Ontario, Newfoundland, Wisconsin, Illinois, Indiana, Minnesota, South Dakota, Iowa, Nebraska, Missouri, Kentucky, West Virginia, Washington, British Colombia, the Caribbean or Central America, don't see where it'

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm planning on densarmor or similar which all my reading says will be fine. My real question is more about the fire blocking -- I have to solve that before I can get to framing and sheetrock..